# Best way to traverse dom elements with a condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, parent-child, dom-traversal

Which is the best way to find all elements from page which match the size i need, and less browser overloading ?

the most important thing is to make it so that the browser will not overload and will not crash if on page are a lot of elements.

what i'm using now is:

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
len = elements.length; 
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    if(elements[i].clientHeight == MyHeight && elements[i].clientWidth == MyWidth)
{ /*my code*/ }
```

Please, if anybody knows a better way which don't stress the browser as much as what I'm using now, then this is what i need.

Comment: @MESSIAH what do you mean ?

Comment: i mean are you just asking about the best practice or your code is not functioning?

Comment: I'm  just asking about the best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely **have to do it**, it would be more efficient to iterate through the tree recursively, because then once you hit an element that is less than what you need, you know nothing inside of it can be the required size. Still seems like there would be a better solution under most circumstances, but I don't know your specific problem.

EDIT:

This works.

```
function findElements( width, height, element ){
    var results = Array();

    for( var i=0; i<element.childNodes.length; i+=1 ){
        var childElement = element.childNodes[i];

        if( childElement.clientWidth == width && childElement.clientHeight == height ){
            results.push(childElement);
            results = results.concat(findElements(width, height, childElement));

        } else if( childElement.clientWidth < width || childElement.clientHeight < height ){
            continue;

        } else {
            results = results.concat(findElements(width, height, childElement));
        }
    }

    return results;
}

findElements(myWidth, myHeight, document);
```

Comment: I like your suggestion, seems useful. Please show me your sample code for that. I would like to iterate throught the tree and check the parent element if its size is greater or smaller and continue only if it is greater , because this way i will iterate only thru few elements and not all unnecessary.  I'm not very good at javascript, please show me your sample code. thanks +1

Comment: I said it was example code to give you an idea. I'm not going to write it for you, but you're pretty close regardless.

Comment: Made a minor fix. Try again.

Comment: ok. thanks Ryan. I will try to find the best way and and get the function written, but my javascript skills are as beginner level

Comment: this minor fix i did myself before ... it is not the problem, the problem is in the whole code algorithm, so it not works as should

Comment: That doesn't mean the problem is the whole algorithm.

Comment: I just tested it on this page in my console for 32 X 32 and it showed me all of the avatars very quickly. So it does work as is. Maybe you should make sure clientHeight/clientWidth are what you want to check.

Comment: Try putting it in a window onload event.

Answer (score 0):

I think we are talking about speed here.(though the difference is marginal).

[Who is the fastest???](http://jsperf.com/js-vs-jquery-select-all/2) -->click the run button and test it your self!!!

I guess  `document.body.querySelectorAll("*");` is a clear winner.

```
var items = document.body.querySelectorAll("*");
     var target, i, len = items.length;
     for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
       target=items[i];
if(//your condition)
    { and the code}
```

[image: Winner!!!]

**Conclusion:**Just write code which are understandable,readable and elegant.I think understanding the logic is the most trivial part.

UPDATE:

```
function findParentNode() {

    var testObj = document.body.querySelectorAll("*");;
    for(var i=0;i<=testObj.length;i++){
      if(testobj.offsetWidth=="your width" && testobj.offsetHeight=="your height"){
            //push it in an array or do whatever you wanted to do 
          }
     else{
     //no elements found!!!
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Javascript Body (TagName) 707 ±2.04%
fastest, this means that my question code sample is fastest than yours. i just followed your link and pasted the results.

Comment: and it also depends on the content ..did you replace the content??

Comment: @MESSIAH Nothing you wrote is algorithmically any different from what he originally posted.

Comment: i guess he is not asking for logic,he is asking about the performance!!!i guess i am not wrong..

Comment: @ManY:hii,even i replaced your code and tested...i think every time i run it, i get some varied results..but still `document.body.querySelectorAll("*");` comes out the winner!!!i just tested it..

Comment: Testing in Chrome 28.0.1500.72 32-bit on Windows Server 2008 R2 / 7 64-bit  .. and results shows me that document.body.getElementsByTagName("*"); is the fastest

Comment: yes,i think iwe have to get down to a conclusion.And obviously many aspects come in to play here including your code,cross browsers...

Comment: Alright, i did my own test and it shown me good results, so your answer is right !!! it is best so far !

Comment: @MESSIAH you are right, I'm looking for performance, and querySellector is faster, but also Ryan suggested an algorithm. Can you please help me make it using your suggestion with Ryan suggestion and build the best answer so i can sellect it as winner. I'm looking to check parent element if sizes are biger or equal then we go thru it , but if sizes are smaller we skip it and go to next parent element from the dom tree elements. Can you add such sample to your answer, because i think this will be the best answer i think

Comment: sure,i would..but i think giving correct answer is the motivation here..not the selection!!!

Comment: @ManY The only way to do that is something like I posted. If he wants to write it for you, then give him the answer.

Comment: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/06/26/how-to-find-and-access-parent-nodes-via-javascript/
not exactly what you want,but might help!!!Rather than first finding the parentnode and then calulating their width and then comparing..just go through all the elements...or you can also go the  ryan way!!!good luk with your project!!!